# getting error when I compile the Java code using package in commandline?

Tags: java, command-line, compilation, directory, package

I have this directory structure:

```
project1/src/edu/course/firstweek/javacourse/Program1.java
```

Another file in one package above:

```
project1/src/edu/course/firstweek/program2.java
```

In the header of program2.java, I have

```
package edu.course.firstweek;

import edu.course.firstweek.javacourse.Program1;
```

Now to when I run the following in commandline:

`Javac src/edu/course/firstweek/program2.java,` I get this error:

```
src/edu/course/firstweek/program2.java:14:error cannot find symbol
      System.out.println(program1.print("hello world"));

   symbol:   variable Program1
   location: class program2
2 errors
```

I can see that the compiler is not able to find the `program1`,but I have the correct `import` `package` statement in `program2`. I need help here and after compiling, is there something that needs to be taken into account for running the program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going into one directory inside, i.e. `cd src`
and then compile `Javac edu/course/firstweek/program2.java`

for running, do `java edu.course.firstweek.program2`

Comment: huh! this worked, but why is that going into `src` made the difference?

Comment: Because it gives you an implicit CLASSPATH of '.', and '.' is now the top of your package hierarchy. You should always be there when compiling.

Comment: @EJP: what needs to be done to make it work if I have not done `cd src` that is I am not in '.' correct?