# how to compile interdependent packages in Java?

Tags: java, package, classpath, javac

I have two `packages` in my project folder:

`src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*` and `src/main/java/com/scg/util/*`.  Both of them have `classes` that `import` others.
eg:
`import com.scg.util.Address` in one of the `Class` in `src/main/java/com/scg/domain/`
and `import com.scg.domain.TimeCard` in one of the `Class` in `src/main/java/com/scg/util/`.
Now I want to compile all the `Java files` in `both packages`.

To compile all the `Java files` in `src/main/java/com/scg/util/`

I tried this:

```
javac -cp src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*:src/main/java/com/scg/util/* src/main/java/com/scg/util/*
```

but it gave me 72 errors. I am pasting a sample of it:

```
src/main/java/com/scg/domain/ClientAccount.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
public final class ClientAccount implements Account {
                                            ^
  symbol: class Account
src/main/java/com/scg/domain/ConsultantTime.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    private Account account;
            ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class ConsultantTime
src/main/java/com/scg/domain/ConsultantTime.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    public ConsultantTime(final Date date, final Account account,
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class Account
  location: class ConsultantTime
src/main/java/com/scg/domain/ConsultantTime.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    public Account getAccount() {
```

what is the easiest way to `compile` all the `java files` in two `packages` where there is dependency (I mean `import` here).

Comment: How did you forget? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776757/2970947

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: that one is for a single java file. I want to do compile all class file. the wildcard `*` does not work.

Comment: @eagerToLearn See my answer in your original question, or indeed the one you asked in November, and just change the filename to `*.java`. This question is so similar that it should have been posted with your original question. Ditto the answer. Please don't clutter up this sites with duplicates and triplicates.

Comment: @EJP: well I tried *.java and it did not work. I posted original question 3 hours back and no reply came. so I modified it here a little

Comment: And everybody is telling you not to do that. If you had edited your original question it would have popped up to the top of the list again and we wouldn't be having this conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile all the Java source files at once:

```
javac src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*.java src/main/java/com/scg/util/*.java
```

Your classpath option is useless, and not valid. The classpath is supposed to contain directories or jar files containing the root of a package tree, containing already compiled classes used by the source files you want to compile.

Compiling many files from the command line is useful to understand the mechanisms of the compilation. But you should really learn to use a build tool like Gradle or Ant to build your project, and an IDE to compile and test your classes during development.

EDIT:

Reading [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) again, you can use -cp to specify path where sources must be found. But the root of the package tree must be specified:

```
-cp src/main/java
```

Comment: I was using maven. but the way you do in commandline is different than using mvn commands

Comment: This answer isn't correct. He doesn't have to compile all the Java source at once. If he was in the correct directory, i.e. `src/main/java,` he could issue `javac com/scg/domain/*.java` or `javac com/scg/util/*.java` and all the required dependencies would get compiled.

Comment: Well, he isn't in this directory.

Comment: @user1988876: if you're using Maven, why do you compile your files using javac. Let Maven compile them. That's what it's for.

Comment: And he should be in that directory, and that's another possibility, and your answer excludes all other possibilities by its language.

Comment: Agreed about the language. Changed must to should. Compiling everything at once is the best option, IMHO. That's what build tools do. Disagree that he should be in the source directory to compile files. Changing directories everytime a command must be executed is cumbersome. You can stay at the root, and provide appropriate paths and options to javac and java.

Comment: I think we only disgree about what the 'root' is. IMHO it is `src/main/java` for all the purposes you mention. Another option is to stay where you like it and use `-sourcepath src/main/java.`

Comment: @JBNizet: I tried what you suggested, but I get this message:  `error: package org.slf4j does not exist
import org.slf4j.Logger;`. That clearly means `slf4j is not in my classpath`. so I tried: `javac -cp /Users/meee/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/ src/main/java/com/scg/domain/*.java src/main/java/com/scg/util/*.java`, that still failed with same error..

Comment: The jar file of slf4j needs to be in the classpath. Not the directory containing the jar. But once again: use Maven to compile your project, since you already have a Maven project.